# Error Running 'react-native run-android' on ubuntu 14

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio, react-native

I have been trying to setup run my first react native project and have followed the steps provided [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). But i keep getting this error when i run

> $ react-native run-android

what i get is this

```html
Starting JS server...
    Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
    Unzipping /home/webshinobis/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.4-all/6r4uqcc6ovnq6ac6s0txzcpc0/gradle-2.4-all.zip to /home/webshinobis/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.4-all/6r4uqcc6ovnq6ac6s0txzcpc0
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:159)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$500(Install.java:26)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:69)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:46)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:46)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:126)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

I have searched and all i have seen so far are genymotion user solutions.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, i found the error, the zip file  in

> /home/webshinobis/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.4-all/6r4uqcc6ovnq6ac6s0txzcpc0/gradle-2.4-all.zip

was corrupt that's y it could not be unzipped by the java. 
So I have to go into the folder and delete the zip file mannualy and then run

> react-native run-android

again. Hope that helps someone else. This is usually due to internet connection issues.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `ANDROID_HOME` environment variables. Check your `adb devices` first. If your device is available. See the [cyprusglobe suggestion](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8868).

Run:

```
- chmod 755 android/gradlew
- react-native run-android
```

Comment: If you are using the latest Android Studio, set the latest `buildToolsVersion` in your `build.gradle` file.